# Tool Tip for <h:selectManyListbox>

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to added tool tip for selectmanylistbox,i tried in various ways but i could 't make it happen please help me.

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="sourceList" var="item1"
    value="#{definitionRuleTriggerMBean.selectedSourceValues}"
    style="width: 165px; height: 150px">
        <f:converter converterId="mvCodeMasterConverter" />
        <f:selectItems id="selectid"
            value="#{definitionRuleTriggerMBean.availableCodes}" var="item" 
            itemDescription="#{item.masterCode} #{item.masterCodeDesc}"
            itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.masterCode} 
            #{item.masterCodeDesc}" >
        </f:selectItems>
        <rich:tooltip for="selectid"  value="#{item1.masterCode} 
            #{item1.masterCodeDesc}" /> 
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Comment: what are the "various ways" that you tried ?

Comment: `for` attribute is not correct for `tooltip` tag in RF 4.3 (it is valid attribute in RF 3, but it is not supported in RF 4). Change `value` attribute: call bean method. Example: `<rich:tooltip mode="ajax" styleClass="tooltip" layout="block">    <h:outputText value="#{bean.tooltipText}" />    </rich:tooltip>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what version of richfaces you're using, your `<rich:tooltip/>` is targeted at the wrong component: `sourceList` should be the target, not `selectid`.

Depending on the version of RF you're using, `for` might not be a valid attribute. It's been replaced by the `target` attribute in RF4.x

Ultimately, you don't need to specify either `target` or `for` on the `<rich:tooltip/>`, it's going to automatically attach itself to its parent (if it's nested in another component)